# How do I turn off value validation in SSRS?

Tags: c#, validation, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS system set up to let users subscribe to periodic reports. Some of the reports have a parameter, EmployerGroup, that they choose from a list. The thing is that employer groups sometimes get deactivated, and if a user sets up a report subscription that includes an Employer Group that later gets deactivated, instead of just ignoring that group, the report errors out. There seems to be some kind of validation to make sure that all the values are valid before the report gets run. Is there any way of turning this validation off or some other way to fix this problem?

Couple things: (1) When a group is deactivated, it remains in the database and is merely flagged as inactive. (2) I really don't know that much about SSRS. This system was set up like this when I started working on it.

Comment: What do you expect for subscriptions with deactivated EmployerGroups, spot them, delete them or keep generating the report without the deactivated EmployerGroups? What about subscriptions with deactivated EmployerGroups only, do you want to generate empty reports?

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, what is probably happening is that the report dataset that retrieves the "available values" for the EmployerGroup parameter is filtering out values that have been flagged as inactive. When the report subscription runs, the supplied Employer Group value in the subscription doesn't match any of the available values in the report parameter and so you get an error.

It sounds like you need a process to detect report subscriptions with parameters that are no longer valid (e.g. inactive Employer Groups) so that they can be changed or removed. Without knowning more about your system I can't say how that could be implemented.